# adding id attribute when linking stylesheet from themeName.info

Tags: theming

I am working on drupal theme. In past, i linked stylesheets via the themeName.info file as follows:

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/thickbox/thickbox.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/custom.css
```

However, this time i need the particular css file link, so it has an ID attribute set as following:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jquery-colorbox-css'  href='/assets/css/colorbox.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

How would i link the style sheet from the themeName.info file, so that it has ID set to 'jquery-colorbox-css' along the extra attribute 'media' included as well. Thank you a lot

Comment: Thank You Frazras. So, in another words, it is not doable at this time. Is there somewhere something like 'good to have' list in Drupal community where i could, perhaps, post this as an item good to have?thnks

Comment: You could post it as an issue to drupal core themeing layer. An alternate solution is to manually put it in the html.tpl.php file (making a comment note in the .info file for unsuspecting developers)